# Titles that do not describe the question properly should be edited

Tags: discussion, editing

Before asking [my latest question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9239/is-it-mandatory-to-use-a-comma-before-a-conjunction-uniting-the-two-clauses-in-a), I searched for "[compound sentence conjunction](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=compound+sentence+conjunction)". Most of the questions' title were so uninformative that I had to click through each time to know whether my question had been already answered.

For example the question "[Comma in compound/complex sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4828/comma-in-compound-complex-sentences)" doesn't tell you enough information about its content. It's only by clicking through that you know what is being asked.

The goal of StackExchange is to [help us build a great library of canonical answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/). Having poor titles like that is counterproductive to that goal, because it makes searching the library much more painful than it ought to be. So, when you see a title that doesn't tell you what the question is, and you can improve, you should.

Answer (score 5):

Yes -- I agree. I am sure everyone agrees that editing with the intent to make the question clearer and easier to understand is always a net positive for the community and is welcome.

What exactly is the question?

Comment: I wasn't aware that all posts on metas had to be questions. I only saw a problem while using English.SE and thought I'd mention it on meta since I'm unlikely to get the reputation to fix it myself any time soon.

Comment: @borr we are working on allowing provisional edits from all users so stay tuned to http://blog.stackoverflow.com in the next few weeks

Comment: @Borror: Good that you brought this to everyone's attention; I wasn't even fully aware that we could edit titles.