# Would I have been flagged for posting a question with a swear word in the title?

Tags: discussion, titles, bowdlerization, offensive

I've posted [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154530/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-crazier-than-a-shthouse-rat/154583?noredirect=1#154583) about the origins of the phrase crazier than a shithouse rat.

And, in an attempt to soften the blow to some of our more "sensitive" readers, I chose to post the term as sh*thouse rat.

Need I have done that?  Or, as a language usage site are words that might be deemed offensive but not hateful acceptable?

In my personal life, I am not one to watch my language except in situations where decorum is absolutely required.  I feel that America is too puritanical in our view of words derived from Anglo-Saxon English.

Comment: Why do Brits insist on putting the good stuff on page 3? So puritanical!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Titles, but not post bodies or tags, [must be censored for profanity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/975/do-we-really-need-to-add-nsfw-in-question-titles?lq=1) because they may appear on other sites on the Stack Exchange network where users are not expecting to see profanity in any form. It is not necessary to censor profanity in post bodies or tags if it is a legitimate discussion of said profanity, but using profanity for profanity's sake is not permitted.

Comment: Cool!  Thanks for the info!  I will put this into practice immediately.